# How to add composed column into the WHERE condition of MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm composing a new field (i.e. distance) in my SQL query result, and would like to use that (i.e. distance) as a condition of filtering my query.

```
SELECT status, id, location, ABS(location - (100)) as distance FROM mytable WHERE ( status='approved' AND distance < '0.1') ORDER BY distance ASC
```

I could use that (i.e. distance) for sorting, but when put in the WHERE side of condition, it complaint

## 1054 - Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'

What's the best workaround of resolving this (i.e. I still want to filter by distance). Thanks.

Comment: You need to repeat the condition `WHERE ( status='approved' AND ABS(location - (100))< '0.1')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two common solutions:

Option 1: Add the condition instead of the alias. Hopefully the query optimizer will calculate it only once.

```
SELECT status, id, location, ABS(location - (100)) as distance 
FROM mytable 
WHERE status='approved' AND ABS(location - (100)) < '0.1'
```

Option 2: Make a subselect and use the alias in the outer select.

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT status, id, location, ABS(location - (100)) as distance 
  FROM mytable) x
WHERE status='approved' AND distance < '0.1'
```

There is a third that might also work, and it's using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`. `HAVING` is applied later (after aggregations) and therefore allows the use of aliases. Usually `HAVING` is used together with `GROUP BY`, and therefore using it by itself might be confusing when you later have to review this query, so I would recommend one of the other two options.

```
SELECT status, id, location, ABS(location - (100)) as distance 
FROM mytable 
HAVING status='approved' AND distance < '0.1'
```

Comment: Thanks GolezTrol! I love the second approach. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can't use it like this, instead try it like this

```
SELECT status, id, location, ABS(location - (100)) as distance FROM mytable WHERE ( status='approved' AND ABS(location - (100)) < 0.1) ORDER BY distance ASC
```

Comment: Thanks michael. I prefer GolezTrol answer above, as I don't need to write the formula twice.

Comment: His answer is better honestly, I upvoted his answer, too! @Elye